# Return value in Excel (a la VLOOKUP) ONLY when another condition also matches

Tags: excel, conditional-statements, vlookup

I have two tables in Excel.
Table 1 includes unique identifiers and valuable information on those identifiers in one condition.  However, the unique identifiers can be listed multiple times (if the condition changes).

Table 2 records separate information, but I want it to use the unique-identifiers from Table 1 and return some of the information listed in Table 1.  I can easily use either VLOOKUP or INDEX and MATCH to do so, and it of course returns the information from whichever condition is listed first (if the unique ID appears multiple times).

I can see the logic of maybe using an AND statement (combined with IF) to match the condition from columns in Table 1 and Table 2, but how do I then force my formula to only return the information when that AND statement is true?  What I absolutely do not want to do is make the duplicated identifiers more unique by combining them with the condition.

Also, all of this is qualitative data/character strings.

**Edit 10/23/14**

I had a request for a visual. In it's simplest form, I'm trying to duplicate the information from Table 1 in Table 2 (though in truth both tables have mutually exclusive data).
So if I have entered individual clients entry into different programs in Table 1:
[image]

And then in Table 2, I want column C to recognize that if the identifier is paired with the specific program label in column A (I have six programs, hundreds of identifiers), it will print the entry date appropriate for that Client in that Program:

 [image]

Comment: Can you post a few sample data and expected output? (simplest you can come up with). Screen shots will do, just upload it in a free image hosting site (e.g. http://imgur.com/) and post the link in your question.

Comment: Thanks--I've made that change.  I hope it's elucidating.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way may be to insert a new ColumnA into the sheet (say Sheet1) that holds your first table, say:

```
    =B2&"|"&C2
```

copied down to suit. This would then serve as a key for a lookup formula such as:

```
=VLOOKUP(B2&"|"&A2,Sheet1!A:D,4,0)
```

in C2 of your other sheet, copied down to suit.